# How to clone tenant in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I would like to clone tenant in Alfresco and don't know how to better realize it.

Maybe exist some add-ons or some API which could be utilized?

Comment: Why clone? What purpose? Is creating a new tenant and exporting/importing data not good enough?

Comment: I would like during exporting handle nodes. For example copy all groups but not users, copy locked nodes.